# Designing a Language Lexer

Tags: parsing, language-design, lexer

I'm currently in the process  of creating a programming language. I've laid out my entire design and am in progress of creating the Lexer for it. I have created numerous lexers and lexer generators in the past, but have never come to adopt the "standard", if one exists.

**Is there a specific way a lexer should be created to maximise capability to use it with as many parsers as possible?**

Because the way I design mine, they look like the following:

Code:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

Lexer:

```
[
KEYWORD:INT, IDENTIFIER:"main", LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET, RIGHT_ROUNDBRACKET, LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET,
IDENTIFIER:"printf", LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET, STRING:"Hello, World!", RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET, COLON,
RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET
]
```

Is this the way Lexer's should be made? **Also as a side-note, what should my next step be after creating a Lexer?** I don't really want to use something such as ANTLR or Lex+Yacc or Flex+Bison, etc. I'm doing it from scratch.

Comment: It is a 21st century already. Stop using lexers. Lexerless parsing is by far more efficient and versatile.

Comment: @SK-logic Care to elaborate? ;)

Comment: With a lexerless parser (e.g., GLR or a PEG) you don't have to limit your language to a fixed, context-independent set of tokens. Tokens can be context sensitive, which allows complex behaviour (e.g., string interpolation syntax, mixing very different languages together, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a parser generator [Note 1], then it is absolutely up to you how your lexer provides information to your parser.

Even if you do use a parser generator, there are many details which are going to be project-dependent. Sometimes it is convenient for the lexer to *call* the parser with each token; other times is is easier if the parser calls the lexer; in some cases, you'll want to have a driver which interacts separately with each component. And clearly, the precise datatype(s) of your tokens will vary from project to project, which can have an impact on how you communicate as well.

Personally, I would avoid use of global variables (as in the original yacc/lex protocol), but that's a general style issue.

Most lexers work in streaming mode, rather than tokenizing the entire input and then handing the vector of tokens to some higher power. Tokenizing one token at a time has a number of advantages, particularly if the tokenization is context-dependent, and, let's face it, almost all languages have some impurity *somewhere* in their syntax. But, again, that's entirely up to you.

Good luck with your project.

---

#### Notes:

1. Do you also forgo the use of compilers and write all your code from scratch in assembler or even binary?

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer, reading it now. For your note, I'm not going **that** far, I'm probably writing it in Python or C for now.

Comment: When you state that it is better to tokenise one-at-a-time, would it be preferable to include syntax checking during tokenisation, to make sure the correct token follows? **Example: INT can only be followed by OPERATOR, otherwise throw an error???**

Comment: @frayment: Syntax checking is the job of the parser. The lexer should avoid having any knowledge beyond the nature of lexical tokens, while the parser shouldn't have to worry about the characters which form a token. That's the traditional separation of concerns. (So, for example, parsers shouldn't ever see whitespace or comments.) There are people who prefer "scannerless parsers" but I'm not one of them so I'm not going to expand on that comment :)

Comment: @frayment: And my little joke about assembler is based on the question: Why would you avoid a higher level tool which will make your life easier? Presumably you use Python because it's got lots of goodies which would be annoying to implement and make your programs shorter and more readable; why then is it somehow virtuous to not use a parser generator? I don't even believe that it helps you understand "how to parse" since you're not going to implement the optimal algorithm (LALR, again IMHO) precisely because it's annoying to implement (see above), so you'll end up with recursive descent.

Comment: ... but, then, that's all getting opinionated :) So, again, good luck with the project.

Comment: Thankyou! I'm probably going to stick with LLR(1) parsing, and chose to use something such as Python due to the simplicity and readability. As for not using a parser generator, I found a good quote somewhere which explains everything; I'll look for it now...

Comment: "I wouldn't bother wasting time with lexer or parser generators and other so-called "compiler compilers." They're a waste of time. Writing a lexer and parser is a tiny percentage of the job of writing a compiler. Using a generator will take up about as much time as writing one by hand, and it will marry you to the generator (which matters when porting the compiler to a new platform). And generators also have the unfortunate reputation of emitting lousy error messages." - http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-language/240165488

Comment: Theres more to it though, I (stupidly) just dont trust generators, and want to challenge myself to see what I can come up with. Worst comes to worst, Ill probably go with a Lex-Yacc derivative or ANTLR.

Comment: @frayment: Yes, I've read that article. It's a good article, but the paragraph you quote is Walter at his most iconoclastic. And it's bad advice. It's true that lexing and parsing is not a huge part of writing a language. You want to write a language, you want to get into the guts of the implementation. Why waste time reinventing a well-studied and well-implemented wheel? The result of your parse should be an AST and possibly a symbol table. You can get that done in a few hours using flex/bison and then you can get started on your actual work...

Comment: Haha, I totally understand. It is my first time however, and am trying to do it the hard way first time around. If you're interested, my GitHub is https://github.com/frayment/. Slowly adding it all together.

Comment: ... If for whatever reason, you want to change the parser later, no problem. You've got the context-free grammar; you can easily change it to a different format if necessary. Since you're only building an AST, there's practically nothing in the rules and good refactoring means that they will be mostly single function calls anyway. It's true that bison parsers tend to produce horrible error messages. But so do hand-written parsers. As Walter says, producing good error messages is hard work.

Comment: Haha, as for error messages, thats already sorted. Implemented numerous loggers and error stacks in Python, Java, etc. That stuff is fun.

Comment: Well, have fun with it. Here's the question I always ask: If you were teaching people how to use dictionaries, would you start by building a hash table in assembler? (Or even C?)? Or would you write a simple python program which showed *what you can do with them*? Which one gives better insight into dictionaries *as a programming tool*? If you don't understand how hash tables are used, you're not going to write a good hash table API, so a novice programmer with no experience in the subject is not going to produce a good low-level library either.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the advice; I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a specific way a lexer should be created to maximise capability to use it with as many parsers as possible?

In the lexers I've looked at, the canonical API is pretty minimal. It's basically:

```
Token readNextToken();
```

The lexer maintains a reference to the source text and its internal pointers into where it is currently looking. Then, every time you call that, it scans and returns the next token.

The Token type usually has:

- A "type" enum for which kind of token it is: string, operator, identifier, etc. There are usually special kinds for "EOF", meaning a special terminator token that is produced after the end of the input, and "ERROR" for the rare cases where a syntax error comes from the lexical grammar. This is mainly just unterminated string literals or totally unknown characters in the source.
- The source text of the token.
- Sometimes literals are converted to their proper value representation during lexing in which case you'll have that value too. So a number token would have "123" as *text* but also have the numeric *value* 123. Or you can do that during parsing/compilation.
- Location within the source file of the token. This is for error reporting. Usually 1-based line and column, but can also just be start and end byte offsets. The latter is a little faster to produce and can be converted to line and column lazily if needed.

Depending on your grammar, you may need to be able to rewind the lexer too.